# Undefined property: stdClass::$categories

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model

How to find all objects only directly through the model, otherwise this function stops working for me in the model (categories and tags attached to Model)

```
$products = DB::table('products')
     ->where('title', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
     ->get();
```

Video to better understand where the problem is - https://youtu.be/44g47p9JAWs

Comment: You are binding only products with the return method so how can you access $categories in the index blade. Can you paste your your index.blade code and productscontroller code here so that I can help you

Comment: Check the video. Function search the same as index.blade.php, but in index I get it by this line - $products = Product::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get(); and think that it's a problem in DB class, because I make this load on search and all tags/categories worked, but in the same time, I get the same array with numeration 0,1,2,3

Comment: If the answer came up, please click the up arrow.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once this is done, you may access the intermediate table data using the customized name.

```
use App/Product

$products = Product::with('tags', 'categories')->where('title', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')->get();
```